# TensorFlow placement algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, tensorflow, distributed

I would like to know when the placement algorithm of TensorFlow (as described in the white paper) gets actually employed. All examples for distributing TensorFlow that I have seen so far seem to specify manually where the nodes should be executed on, using `tf.device()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dynamic placement algorithm described in Section 3.2.1 of the [TensorFlow whitepaper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) was not included in the open-source release. Instead, the "simple placer" (whose implementation can be found in [`simple_placer.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4183d0a284b2b682b78937ac814b1daa926be032/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc)) is used, but it requires some explicit annotations (via [`tf.device()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#device)) to make yield an efficient placement. Higher-level constructs like [`tf.train.replica_device_setter()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#replica_device_setter) wrap `tf.device()` to specify common policies such as "shard the variables across parameter servers, and otherwise put all ops on the worker device," and we use this extensively in [distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/distributed/index.html).

In practice we have found that a small set of annotations usually yields a more efficient placement than the dynamic placer will determine, but improving the placement algorithm remains an area of active research.

Comment: +mrry Thanks for your answer. Is there some plan to release the dynamic placer in the forseeable future?

Comment: +mrry Nevermind, I just noticed that this question is discussed in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2126